# How can I search and replace a piece of text in an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have two types of XML files that hold details of retro games. I'm trying to dynamically edit the files to search and replace a games title.

I'm not sure if this is a problem that will need two distinct solutions or not but thought I would detail it here and, hopefully, you will be able to steer me towards a solution.

The first XML file has this type of structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<LaunchBox>
  <Game>
    <Status>Imported ROM</Status>
    <DatabaseID>22190</DatabaseID>
    <Title>ME-Title Match Pro Wrestling</Title>
    <UseDosBox>false</UseDosBox>
    <Version>(USA)</Version>
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Status>Imported ROM</Status>
    <DatabaseID>30128</DatabaseID>
    <Title>Skeet Shoot</Title>
    <UseDosBox>false</UseDosBox>
    <Version>(USA)</Version>
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Status>Imported ROM</Status>
    <DatabaseID>28694</DatabaseID>
    <Title>Star Strike</Title>
    <UseDosBox>false</UseDosBox>
    <Version>(USA)</Version>
  </Game>
</LaunchBox>
```

The second file (the extension is `.dat` but it looks like an xml inside) has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE datafile PUBLIC "-//Logiqx//DTD ROM Management Datafile//EN">
<datafile>
    <header>
        <name>MatchingDATTest</name>
    </header>
    <game name="KeepAway (USA)">
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>
    <game name="Super Football Another Game">
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>
    <game name="River Raid II (USA)">
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>
    <game name="London Blitz (USA)">
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>
</datafile>
```

I would like to be able to have code that basically says...

Find `<Title>Star Strike</Title>` and replace with `<Title>Star Wars</Title>`

Or, in the case of the other type of file...

Find `<game name="KeepAway (USA)">` and replace with `<game name="KeepAway 2 (USA)">`

I wasn't sure the best way to approach this problem? Whether to `fopen` the file and somehow go line by line through it but these files can get very large (up to 100,000 games) so I thought that might not be practical? Following a lot of Googling and experimenting over the last few days I cobbled together this code from other solutions to similar problems.

This was trying to deal with the first example of XML that I posted.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($fileToEdit);
$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$found = false;
// look for the document element
do {
  $found = $found ? $reader->next() : $reader->read();
} while (
  $found && 
  $reader->localName !== 'LaunchBox'
);
// go to first child of the document element
if ($found) {
    $found = $reader->read();
}
// found a node at depth 1 
while ($found && $reader->depth === 1) {
    // We need to check if we're dealing with an Element
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'Game')
    {
        // Let's inspect the node's content as well
        while ($reader->read())
        {
            if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT)
            {
                $thisValue = $reader->value;
                if( $thisValue == $gameTitleToSearchFor ){
                    $reader->value = $gameTitleToReplaceWith;
                    break 2;                      
                }

            }
        }
    }
    $found = $reader->next();
}
$dom->save($fileToEdit);
$reader->close();
```

But I get an error saying `Cannot write to read-only property` so I'm waving the white flag as this is beyond my ability at the moment so wondered if anyone could help?

Comment: I've never seen/used `XMLReader`. Do you need to use that? I would use `SimpleXML` or `DomDocument`. I suspect that is only a reader though and the reason you receive `read-only` error.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks

Comment: The files look pretty straightforward, so you could do it quick and dirty; Read the file with `$data = file_get_contents('file.xml')`, run a `$data = str_replace('<Title>old name</Title>', '<Title>new name</Title>', $data)` and then save it again using `file_put_contents('file.xml', $data)`. If you include the `<Title></Title>` tags, it would be highly unlikely it would replace the wrong text.

Comment: @M.Eriksson would that be a practical solution even on much larger files? These xml files can be up to 200Mb in size? If it would work like that then I'd be happy to mark this as a solution? Thank you very much for you help and suggestion.

Comment: @user3783243 thank you. To be honest I don't really know the difference between them. I was cobbling the code together by standing on the shoulders of giants and it's a bit above my head. I'll certainly look more into your suggestions though - thanks.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky thank you - I will Google XSLT and see what comes up - I've never heard of it. Much appreciated.

Comment: XSLT is indeed the best tool to process XML. But it is not clear where your find/replace pairs are coming from. Do you intend to hard-code them into the solution or are they supposed to be looked up from somewhere?

Comment: Two suggestions:1) Since the file size might be important, gzip the xml source file and [use the `zlib://` wrapper to build the file url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php). 2) XMLReader/XMLWriter is a possible combo if you don't want to load the whole file, but it isn't very handy (but not impossible). A more simple way is to use this library: https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator

Comment: @michael.hor257k: the main problem is: to use XSLT in php you have to create a DOMDocument object from the xml source, and when the xml source is big it takes a lot of time and a lot of memory. An alternative is to launch (eventually from PHP) an xsltproc command.

Comment: At 200 MB, PHP's [XSL class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) will work fine even with laptop level of 8 GB RAM.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the code is running locally via Xampp. The find/replace pairs come from a form via a browser. The user (i.e. me as this is just a project I'm working on as a hobby) can pick alternate titles from a list and then (I'm hoping) this will change the text in the XML file. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a parameterized XSLT using PHP's [XSLTProcessor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) class where you pass parameters from PHP to the stylesheet prior to transformation.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- DEFINE PARAMS -->
    <xsl:param name="find-value"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace-value"/>

   <!-- UPDATE ANY ELEMENT TEXT -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text() = $find-value">
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace-value"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- UPDATE ANY ATTRIBUTE VALUE -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = $find-value">
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace-value"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```php
function UpdateXML($xmlFile, $findParam, $replaceParam) {
    // LOAD XML
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->load($xmlFile);
    
    // LOAD XSLT 
    $xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
    $xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');
    
    // INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
    
    // PASS PARAMETER VALUES
    $proc->setParameter('', 'find-value', $findParam);
    $proc->setParameter('', 'replace-value', $replaceParam);

    // TRANSFORM SOURCE
    $new_xml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
    
    // RETURN OUTPUT
    return $new_xml;
}

// UPDATE XML
$new_launchbox_xml = UpdateXML("Launchbox.xml", "Star Strike", "Star Wars");
// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents("NewLaunchbox.xml", $new_launchbox_xml);


// UPDATE XML
$new_games_xml = UpdateXML("Games.dat", "KeepAway (USA)", "KeepAway 2 (USA)");
// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents("NewGames.xml", $new_games_xml);
```

Should you need to pass multiple values for each XML document, update the method to receive equal length arrays for find and replace values. Then, incorporate a for loop inside method to iteratively call `setParameter`.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write all that out. For some reason it is only saving a blank document when I run the function? I have echoed out the "loading" of the XML and XSL files and they are both being loaded correctly. Any ideas why it would not be saving correctly? Thanks for all your help. ** Edit ** Manage to get it to save by using $new_launchbox_xml->save(Launchbox.xml"); instead of file_put_contents... Although it's removing all the newlines and saving as one big file... any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: right I've sussed it so I've accepted your answer. I wondered if you wouldn't mind updating your answer. I have had to remove the line ```<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>``` which has stopped my output being stripped of all the line breaks. I've also changed the code to be ```$new_xml->save("NewLaunchbox.xml");``` rather than using file_put_contents. Many thanks for all your help I would NEVER have worked all this out without you. You're a superstar!!! :-)

Comment: See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76649970/revisions) to both XSLT and PHP. To render a string version of XML for `file_put_contents` we should use `transformToXML`. Also, XSLT change ensures elements with attributes reproduce with or without text change.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-off requirement then there are many ad-hoc ways of solving it; global replace in an editor, preferably an XML editor, would do the job quite adequately. But if it's part of a production workflow, then XSLT is definitely the right took for the job. The main drawback is that there's a bit of a learning curve, which means that if you're a PHP programmer you might prefer to use the tools you know rather than learning something new.

XSLT version 1.0 is very widely available (it comes "out of the box") and is quite capable of simple jobs like this, though it's a bit more verbose than the latest version, XSLT 3.0, which requires you to install a third party library such as SaxonC (my company's product).

You've given two examples of substitutions you want to perform and the simplest solution would be to write a separate XSLT stylesheet for each one. But if it's a general problem requiring a general solution, and these are just two specific examples, then you could write a single generic stylesheet that takes as parameters the element name, the old text, and the replacement text. A lot depends on whether you want something quick and dirty, or something of production quality that will handle a wide variety of tasks and serve you well for years to come.

Comment: Thank you for the great information. I'm currently wrestling with getting XSL to work but I'm hoping that Parfaits answer below will work when I get it working. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. It's really appreciated :-)